# Clearing yup error messages after resetting the form from api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Is there a way of clearing yup error messages that appear under a text field when resetting the form fields back to values from api call?

I have three fields in a formik form that are preloaded from an api database call together with a `Reset` button that basically reloads these fields again from the api database call.

As part of the reset, I also issue the following for all text fields, for all  fields:

`setFieldValue('myField', item.myField, false)`

If a user causes an error message to appear based on yup validation schema but then presses the `Reset` button again, all values return but the error message still appears below text field.

I have tried `setFieldTouched('myField', false, true)` but this doesn't clear the error message underneath the text field.

Any ideas pls.

Comment: How are you resetting the form?

Comment: @AlexanderNied - I have updated original thread - using `setFieldValue()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resetForm` when click Reset https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#resetform-nextstate-partialformikstatevalues--void

```
handleClickReset = () => resetForm()
```

Comment: But I also need to re-instate the form fields from my backend api call. Can this still be possible?

Comment: You use `setErrors()` instead `resetForm()`

Comment: Any specific parameters I need to pass into `setErrors()` to clear error stack/messages?

Comment: with an empty object: `setErrors({})`